# combine spotbugs filter for Source and Bug together

Tags: findbugs, spotbugs

when running spot bugs against a Jenkins Shared Library, I want to relax a rule for all files beneath the vars/ directory as they will be lowercase "Class" files".

using `<Bug pattern="NM_CLASS_NAMING_CONVENTION" />` or `<Source name="vars/*"/>` alone works but I cannot figure out how to combine them

Using `<And>` or not using it results in the errors showing.

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <And>
            <Bug pattern="NM_CLASS_NAMING_CONVENTION" />
            <Source name="vars/*"/>
        </And>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Is it possible to combine Source + Bug in a match?